# Set high resolution exposure on UVC Camera with Media Foundation

Tags: c++, ms-media-foundation, uvc

I need to set the exposure on a UVC Camera with Media Foundation in a native C++ application with a resolution of milliseconds.

The standard method for setting exposure on a UVC camera via MediaFoundation appears to be using [IAMCameraControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/strmif/nn-strmif-iamcameracontrol) and the [CameraControl_Exposure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/strmif/ne-strmif-cameracontrolproperty) property, using a log2 scaling like this:

```
ComPtr<IAMCameraControl> videoProc;

HRESULT hr = m_mediaSource.As(&videoProc);

long exposure_val = long(std::roundf(std::log2(exposure_ms/1000.0f)));

hr = videoProc->Set(CameraControl_Exposure, exposure_val, CameraControl_Flags_Manual);
```

As per the table in the MS docs, this results in a very coarse range of settings in the low end, making it impossible to get accurate exposure control, which is especially important for higher frame rates.

```
val | Exposure
 .  | .
-3  | 125ms
-4  | 63ms
-5  | 31ms
-6  | 16ms
-7  | 8ms
-8  | 4ms
-9  | 2ms
 .  | .
```

The UVC standard (4.2.2.1.4 Exposure Time (Absolute) Control) defines the exposure resolution as 100us steps, set by the `CT_EXPOSURE_TIME_ABSOLUTE_CONTROL` control selector. So in theory, all UVC 1.5 compliant cameras should be capable of being configured at this high resolution of exposure.

I have looked through all the MediaFoundation documentation and cannot find a method for controlling the exposure at this resolution rather than the scaled method. So this seems to be a limitation of MF itself. How can it be done?

A similar question was asked in 2020 but was never properly answered:

- [Media Foundation Exposure in milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63124813/media-foundation-exposure-in-milliseconds)